# Exception occurred with lw on MIPS SPIM

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I wanted to load a word from the array, so I wrote:

(a1 is a array pointer)

```
   addi $t4, $a0, 0
   addi $t2, $0, 0

calL1:

   lw $t0, 0($t4)             # t0 = $a1[i]

   addi $t4, $t4, 4

   lw $t1, 0($t4)             # t1 = $a1[i+1] 

   add $t2, $t2, 1            # i = i + 1

   bne $s3, $t2, calL1
```

An exception occurs at `lw $t4, 0($t4)`, however, I couldn't determine what's wrong.

I tried `lw $t1, 0($a1)` and it worked well.  What could be causing the exception, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Try editing your post and adding more of your mips code. I presume you're getting either an alignment exception [or non-existent memory]. From what you've posted, `$a0` isn't set up correctly, but the setup code for it isn't part of your post. Or, `$t3` isn't set correctly, and your loop may have many more iterations than you think [and you're running off the end of the allocated data segment].

Comment: Here is how to diagnose the problem: (1) Is $a0 a multiple of 4?  (2) What is the value of $t2 when the exception occurs?